# R tinytex execution failed with error code 127

Tags: r, tinytex

Is there anybody who can help me ??
Ive been struggling to install tinytex here is the result ->

```
tinytex::install_tinytex()
trying URL 'http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip'
Content length 333 bytes
downloaded 23.1 MB

trying URL 'https://yihui.org/gh/tinytex/tools/pkgs-custom.txt'
Content length 57 bytes
downloaded 547 bytes

trying URL 'https://yihui.org/gh/tinytex/tools/tinytex.profile'
Content length 57 bytes
downloaded 183 bytes

Starting to install TinyTeX to C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Roaming/TinyTeX. It will take a few minutes.
Please quit and reopen your R session and IDE (if you are using one, such as RStudio or Emacs) and check if tinytex:::is_tinytex() is TRUE.
Warning messages:
1: In shell("install-tl-windows.bat -no-gui -profile=../tinytex.profile",  :
  'install-tl-windows.bat -no-gui -profile=../tinytex.profile' execution failed with error code 127
2: In file.remove("TinyTeX/install-tl.log") :
  cannot remove file 'TinyTeX/install-tl.log', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I tried quit and reopen Rstudio and tinytex:::is_tinytex() returning FALSE

Comment: Have you run `tinytex::install_tinytex()`?

Comment: Maybe you need RTools before you run `install_tinytex`.